# One of the column between two columns should be NOT NULL. How to enforce it in schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following scehma

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable  
(  
    ID                INTEGER DEFAULT(1,1),      
    FirstIdentifier   INTEGER NULL,    
    SecondIdentifier  INTEGER NULL,  
  --.... some other fields .....    
)
```

Now when inserting a value, one of the column between FirstIdentifier and SecondIdentifier should be
NOT NULL. Is there anyway of enforcing it via schema?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is possible with using a [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx):

```
CHECK (FirstIdentifier IS NOT NULL OR SecondIdentifier IS NOT NULL)
```

While CHECK constraints are part of the table (and hence "schema"?), they may not fit the desired definition. The above CHECK is not mutually exclusive, but it could be altered to such.

Happy coding.

Comment: Do you have know if Check constraints can be replicated (in merge replication)?

Comment: @Silverlight Student Sadly, I have not played with replication :( It should work [or not work] as any other table-level schema though.

Comment: no worries, i will post  a new question. Thanks for your help

Comment: This enforces that at least one of the fields is not null. My interpretation of the question is that exactly one should be non null.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but if exactly one of the columns is allowed to be NULL, the CHECK constraint could be CHECK ((FirstIdentifier IS NOT NULL OR SecondIdentifier IS NOT NULL) AND ([FirstIdentifier] IS NULL OR [SecondIdentifier ] IS NULL))

Comment: Is there a convention on how to display this in a database diagram?