# Can I enforce user to enter value in minimum one of many nullable fields in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One of the column between two columns should be NOT NULL. How to enforce it in schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017871/one-of-the-column-between-two-columns-should-be-not-null-how-to-enforce-it-in-s)

I have a table with 5 null able fields and every record must have a value for one of those fields. 
Can I enforce user to enter value in minimum one of many nullable fields in SQL?
Thanx

Comment: Use Check constraint on table.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, using [a `CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx);

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT,
  val1 VARCHAR(32),
  val2 VARCHAR(32),
  val3 VARCHAR(32),
  val4 VARCHAR(32),
  val5 VARCHAR(32),
  CHECK (COALESCE(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5) IS NOT NULL)
);
```

...will require at least one of val1-val5 to be NOT NULL.

Comment: Upvote! Using `COALESCE` is nice idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
ADD CONSTRAINT chkAnyNotNULL CHECK (col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 IS NOT NULL OR ....);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`;

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MyTable

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Col1    INT NULL,
    Col2    INT NULL,
    Col3    INT NULL,
    Col4    INT NULL,
    Col5    INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT OneNonNull CHECK (COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) IS NOT NULL)
)
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 1,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
GO

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Seems I was beaten to it :)