# I need a check constraint on two columns, at least one must be not null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server with two numeric columns.  At least one of these numeric fields must be filled.  How do I write a check constraint to verify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One of the column between two columns should be NOT NULL. How to enforce it in schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017871/one-of-the-column-between-two-columns-should-be-not-null-how-to-enforce-it-in-s)

Comment: @JohnnyHK not duplicate as this question is about 'at least one of two' and that one is about 'only one of two'

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This can be done with a check constraint that verifies null value and matches the result with `or`

```
create table #t (i int
               , j int
               , constraint chk_null check (i is not null or j is not null))
```

The following are the test cases

```
insert into #t values (null, null) --> error
insert into #t values (1, null) --> ok
insert into #t values (null, 1) --> ok
insert into #t values (1, 1) --> ok
```

Answer (score 29):

late answer, but here is a solution for Sql Server for any number of columns to check:

```
CONSTRAINT CK_one_is_not_null CHECK (COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: This works if the columns have the same datatype. Otherwise the system will try to convert in order to check this constraint

Answer (score 0):

**Another option:**

```
CONSTRAINT at_least_one_not_null CHECK (
            COALESCE((col1)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0) +
            COALESCE((col2)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0) > 0
    )
```